# Scraping website with service worker not working

Tags: php, browser

We're trying to scrape a tiktok page to view the amount of posts and likes that each post has. They have just introduced a service worker to load this section of the site, so when we do a normal PHP scrape, it's not returning this section of the site. In all the PHP browser screenshot providers, it looks like that part isn't rendering for that section either https://phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request={url:%22https://www.tiktok.com/@hair.wigs%22,renderType:%22png%22}

Is there anyway we can get this to render? What can we use?

Comment: UPDATE: Do we just have to specify a "delay time" when using something like PhantomJS? maybe it just needs more time to load this section?

Comment: ANOTHER UPDATE: this site managed to capture a screenshot of the post area, but i'm not sure what they are using to do it. Ideally I want the same thing, but I want it returned as txt not an image file https://www.site-shot.com/

Comment: pls write above updates in Question Post